# Node js - Why does it needs a new object to create the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I saw the document on socket.io and I have one question that I don't get.

I know it can do this to create a server:

```
var io = require ("socket.io")();
```

I am wondering why it needs to create a new object instead reference it:

```
//Why this
var server = require ("socket.io");
var io = new server ();
// Why not this
var server = require ("socket.io");
var io = server ();
```

Comment: Please read this: http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/

Comment: Because the people who wrote the server function decided to write it that way.

Comment: @Quentin So you are saying it works fine without creating a new object

Comment: @Qwerty I thought *you* said that with the first snippet?

Comment: @DaveNewton What do you mean?

Comment: I  mean you said you know you can do it that way.

Comment: @DaveNewton There is two ways of doing it. I know one way, but I can't figure out why I have to create a object for the other way. I want to know how to do both ways.

Comment: @Qwerty Why do you say `var io = server();` isn't creating a new object?

Comment: Why not `var io = new (require("socket.io"))()`?

Answer (score 1):

All of the code snippets you posted are equivalent.

It works with and without `new` because inside the exported constructor, there is a check for whether the constructor was invoked with `new` or not. If it wasn't, [it does a `new` internally](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/53cdd8f1fc0155404f260900481defd8d54c119c/lib/index.js#L39). This is a very common method that many modules implement.